# babel + xdef compile error

Tags: macros, babel

The following code throws the error

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 7
```

when I enable the [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel} % uncomment me
\begin{document}
\label{testlabel}
\xdef\mytest{}
\xdef\mytest{\mytest \ref{testlabel}}
\end{document}
```

To provide a bit of context of what I'm trying to accomplish, see the more verbose example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel} % enabling this results in an error
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\xdef\myanswers{}
\newcommand{\myappend}[1]{\xdef\myanswers{\myanswers #1}}
\newcommand{\mycorrect}{\label{risp:\theqcnt}}

\newenvironment{questions}
{\section*{Questions}\vspace{2em}}
{\noindent\textbf{Answers: }\myanswers}

\newcounter{qcnt}
\setcounter{qcnt}{1}
\newenvironment{question}[3]
{\noindent\textbf{Question \theqcnt:}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item #1
\item #2
\item #3
\end{enumerate}
\myappend{\arabic{qcnt}\ref{risp:\theqcnt} }
}
{\vspace{2em}\stepcounter{qcnt}}

\begin{questions}
\begin{question}{first\mycorrect}{second}{third}\end{question}
\begin{question}{first}{second\mycorrect}{third}\end{question}
\begin{question}{first}{second}{third\mycorrect}\end{question}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle true. I'll delete that comment (and alos this one).

Answer (score 3):

You should never use `\edef` or `\xdef` on latex input, you can only use them in controlled situations when you know the tokens involved. You can use the `\protected@edef` or here where you are appending to a macro use

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myappend}[1]{\g@addto@macro\myanswers{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to expand only `\theqcnt`; so use `\protected@xdef` to avoid problems with commands that don't survive `\edef`, but expand `\myanswers` only once and *not* `\label`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % enabling this results in an error
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\def\myanswers{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myappend}[1]{%
  \protected@xdef\myanswers{\unexpanded\expandafter{\myanswers} #1}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mycorrect}{\protect\label{risp:\theqcnt}}

\newenvironment{questions}
  {\section*{Questions}\vspace{2em}}
  {\noindent\textbf{Answers: }\myanswers}

\newcounter{qcnt}
\setcounter{qcnt}{1}

\newenvironment{question}[3]
  {\noindent\textbf{Question \theqcnt:}
   \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
   \item #1
   \item #2
   \item #3
   \end{enumerate}
   \myappend{\arabic{qcnt}\ref{risp:\theqcnt} }%
  }
  {\vspace{2em}\stepcounter{qcnt}}

\begin{questions}
\begin{question}{first\mycorrect}{second}{third}\end{question}
\begin{question}{first}{second\mycorrect}{third}\end{question}
\begin{question}{first}{second}{third\mycorrect}\end{question}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```